# Calling addNewPositionCallback whenever imellipse in GUI axes is moved

Tags: matlab

I have a "Contour Start" button who's callback creates an `imellipse` object at coordinates from `ginput`. Then, I am able to drag the `imellipse` in order to adjust the outline of an image via `addNewPositionCallback`. I calculate intersection points between the `imellipse` and the outline and update the outline accordingly.

Currently, I am only able to update the outline after clicking on the "Contour Start" button, but would like the `addNewPositionCallback` to be called whenever the `imellipse` is moved, not only for the first move after the button press. I attempted to use `waitfor()`, but it did not work.

Axes with imellipse

[image: image1]

Outline adjusted by imellipse after button press on Contour Start
[image: image2]

Outline no longer adjusted by movement of imellipse

[image: image3]

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show some screenshots of the problem? If you don't have enough rep you can post the images on another website and someone here will add them to your post. Thanks!

Comment: My main problem is calling `addNewPositionCallback` whenever `imellipse` is moved, not just on button press. However, I am not sure how I would code this into my GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo showing how to implement a function for the `addNewPositionCallback` method of `imellipse`. That's a simple demo but you will get the idea. If something is unclear please ask.

There is a pushbutton to draw the ellipse and a text box used to display the position of the ellipse (to show it works :).

```
function MoveEllipse
clc
clear
close all

%// Load demo data
I = imread('coins.png');

%// Create GUI
hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 400 400],'Units','normalized');

%// create axes with handle
handles.axes1 = axes('Position', [0.2 0.2 0.6 0.6]);

%// Create pusbutton to draw ellipse
handles.DrawEllipseButton= uicontrol('style', 'push','position', [40 40 100 30],'String','Draw ellipse', 'callback', @(s,e) DrawEllipse);

%// Create edit box to display position
handles.PositionBox = uicontrol('style', 'text','position', [150 30 150 60],'String','','BackgroundColor','w');

%// Show image
imshow(I)

guidata(hFig,handles);


%// Pushbutton callback to draw ellipse.
    function DrawEllipse

        hEllipse = imellipse(gca);

        addNewPositionCallback(hEllipse,@(x) GetEllipsePosition(x))

    end

%// Actual function called by the addNewPositionCallback method
    function GetEllipsePosition(pos)

        set(handles.PositionBox,'String',pos);

    end

end
```

Sample screenshot after pressing the button and moving the ellipse around:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Might I ask why you use an anonymous function rather than directly calling `GetEllipsePosition`?

Comment: You're welcome! Mhh out of habit haha. Actually it enables to use the "default" input (`pos`) returned by the `getPosition()` method which I don't think we can do without the anonymous function.

Comment: On another note, I just realized the better answer to my previous question. I needed a way to update the axes, so I was using `imshow` for the image and replotting all the points. I just realized that I can store the plotted points and delete them. I feel like this might decrease the rather substantial amount of time it takes to update my plots at the moment...

Comment: Yep absolutely. Also, consider refreshing the `CData` property of the handles returned by `imshow` after calling it once. eg `hShow = imshow(...)` and then use `set(hShow,'CData',NewImage)`. This way you call `imshow` only once and it saves a lot of time